# Last modified time of file is different if using sharepoint foundation client object model

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am having one application which is using client object model to access the sharepoint foundation 2010 data. But the LastModifiedTime of the files if you get from client object model is different from what if you see the file in web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property [`SPFile.TimeLastModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.timelastmodified.aspx) returns the date and time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

The same is probably true for the client object model counterpart [File.TimeLastModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.timelastmodified.aspx).

When displaying files in SharePoint, for instance in a document library list view, the dates will be converted to local time defined by the regional settings of the web.

When accessing the modification date column on a `SPListItem` via the API the date and time will be converted to local time as well:

```
SPFile file = ...
// UTC
file.TimeLastModified

SPListItem item = ...
// Local time corresponding to the SPWeb.RegionalSettings
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Modified]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Now i am able to get the Local time corresponding to the web's RegionalSettings for the latest version of the file, but for file version i am not able to get the Local time corresponding to the Web's RegionalSettings.

Comment: @user1107571: can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

@Stefan

I am using the below code for file version....

```
enter code here
SP.File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelatedUrl);
clientContext.Load(file, fv => fv.Name, fv => fv.Exists, fv => fv.TimeLastModified);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
SP.FileVersionCollection fileVersionCollection = file.Versions;
clientContext.Load(fileVersionCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (SP.FileVersion fileVersion in fileVersionCollection)
{
  clientContext.Load(fileVersion, fv => fv.Created);
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  DateTime ModifiedTime = fileVersion.Created;
}
```

Here fileVersion.Created give the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).